# Has anyone successfully re-created the ECB menu on the Data Form web part?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I'd like to use the Data Form web part to display list content from a list in a different site.  I'd also like to show the ECB menu as well to show view properties, edit properties, edit in Microsoft Word (if it is a Word document), etc.

I suppose it is just an exercise in XSLT, but I'd like to know if someone has cracked this nut before and has an example.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the ECB can only be created on a SPGridView.

Here is a [tutorial link](http://www.devexpertise.com/2009/02/25/integrating-a-custom-aspnet-application-into-sharepoint-part-2/) that shows creating the ECB on the grid.

Comment: Nice link and a decent alternative if I cannot use the Data Form web part, but hopefully I don't have to go down that path.